# How to represent a List of List via this data type representation

Tags: list, haskell, types, implementation

using:

```
data type List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
```

How can one represent `[[a]]`? This has to have a simple solution that I'm just blind to so somebody's input would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I was trying to use `List (List a)` or `List (Cons x xs)` but that responds with 'List' not in scope which kinda makes sense to me.

Comment: The type is indeed `List (List a)`, but tha tis for the *type*, not the value.

Comment: If you want to make a list of lists that contains one `1` for example, the *value* is `Cons (Cons 1 Empty) Empty`.

Comment: Also FYI `data type LIst a = ...` is invalid syntax.  This looks like a `data` declaration, there is also a `type` declaration for other purposes.  But not both.

Answer (score 4):

The *type* of a list of lists of `a` is indeed `List (List a))`. But we do not construct a *value* with this.

If we for example want to construct a list with a singleton list that contains `1`, we can write this as:

```
oneList1 :: List (List Int)
oneList1 = Cons (Cons 1 Empty) Empty
```

The outer `Cons` is the cons of the outer list, as first (and only) element it has a `Cons 1 Empty`, this is the inner list. A `Cons h t` represents a list with `h` (here `1`) the head (first element) and `Empty` the tail (remaining elements). So `Cons 1 Empty` is a singleton list with `1` as only value.

We wrap that in the outer cons `Cons (Cons 1 Empty) Empty` that thus specifies that the outer list is a singleton list as well. The `oneList1` is thus equivalent to `[[1]]`.

Comment: Thank you! Been stuck on concatL for this data type for too long... any helpful hints? lol

Comment: @Tempro43: it typically helps to split up into cases that are either base-cases or recursive ones. What would be the `concatL Empty Empty = ...`? or `concatL Empty (Cons x xs) = ...`?, etc.

Comment: Okay, thanks to your response, I got  "concatL (Cons x xs) Empty ) = (Cons x xs) But this seems off. maybe recurse down xs? but what if xs is not of type (List (List a)) and breaks the type signature?? ahhh

Comment: meant "conatL (Cons (Cons x xs) Empty(or xss?)) = (Cons x xs) as to act as a function that takes away the list of lists to single list but then i have to append (or something) those lists together to be one list?

Comment: @Tempro43: `concatL (Cons x xs) Empty = Cons x xs` is correct. No need to recurse on that one. For `concatL (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys)` of course the situationis more complex.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The input has helped my understanding.